# How can I fix "gpg: signing failed: No secret key" for GoReleaser?

Tags: gnupg, gpg-agent, goreleaser

**Context**: Here's a [GoReleaser](https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser-cross) project I'm using.

**How to reproduce**:

1. Export multiple env vars into `.release_env`:

```
GOPATH="..."
GPG_FINGERPRINT="..."
GPG_PASSWORD="..."
GPG_KEY="..."
```

where `GPG_KEY` is `GPG_PRIVATE_KEY` but this project calls it `GPG_KEY`:

> GPG_KEY (optional) - defaults to /secrets/key.gpg. ignored if file not found

2. Run

```
    docker run \
        --rm \
        --env-file .release-env \
        -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
        -v `pwd`:/go/src/$(PACKAGE_NAME) \
        -v `pwd`/sysroot:/sysroot \
        -w /go/src/$(PACKAGE_NAME) \
        goreleaser/goreleaser-cross:v1.20 \
        --rm-dist --skip-validate --skip-publish --debug
```

Then you'll see:

```
    • signing  artifact=my-app_2.0_SHA256SUMS cmd=gpg signature=dist/terraform-provider-confluent-internal_1.34.111111_SHA256SUMS.sig
gpg: directory '/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: skipped "FOOFOOFOOFOOFOOFOOFOOFOO": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
  ⨯ release failed after 51s
```

where `"FOOFOOFOOFOOFOOFOOFOOFOO"` has a value of `GPG_FINGERPRINT` variable.

My ideas:

1. Incorrect values of vars -- I did check they're valid.
2. I should have passed `GPG_PUBLIC_KEY` instead of `GPG_PRIVATE_KEY` for `GPG_KEY`. Based on [this code](https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser-cross/blob/master/entrypoint.sh#L11-L12) it seems like using `GPG_PRIVATE_KEY` is the right idea.
3. Enabled `--debug` mode - did it already and it didn't help much.
4. When I searched for similar questions I could see most of them were about missing gpg executable or something that doesn't seem to be applicable here.
5. Looked at the source code of goreleaser for "signing" stage -- [it looks](https://cs.github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser/blob/a40eb156185ce2c4e6244f8877150cb2b2eaa4c8/internal/pipe/sign/sign.go?q=%22signing%20artifacts%22%20repo%3Agoreleaser%2Fgoreleaser%20) a little bit too advanced for me.
6. I tried passing random strings as `GPG` and it looks like `No secret key` might also indicate wrong value of a key.

At this point I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Did manage to address this?

Comment: @HughWPHamill I don't think so.